What does "= []" mean in C# / .NET Core ? How convert to .NET 4.8?
I have this code in a class in .NET Core:
public IEnumerable<MyDoctor> items { get; set; } = [];

I don't understand the = [] part. What does it mean?
I have an error when I try to compile this in .NET 4.8. How can I convert this code in .NET 4.8 ?

It's a collection expression. What concrete type would you like to be used here? You could use anything you like - Array.Empty<MyDoctor>() would a reasonable option, for example.

Why do you want to "convert" to 4.8? It's probably a better idea to upgrade whatever is in 4.8 to dotnet 8 or even 9?
